# How do JavaScript, Node.js, Express.js, AJAX, JSON, jQuery relate to each other?

Tags: jquery, json, node.js, ajax, express

This is what I (*think I*) understand so far:

- JavaScript is an object-oriented programming language which you can use for client-side apps;
- Node.js is JavaScript framework for writing server-side apps;
- Express.js is "kind of" a framework working on top of Node.js

First of all, are these three points even correct?

Second, what AJAX is, what it is used for, and how does it fit with the rest?

Third, what JSON is, what it is used for, and how does it fit with the rest?

Fourth, what jQuery is, what it is used for, and how does it fit with the rest?

Fifth, is it possible to visualize their connections in a diagram?

Comment: Other than javascript having most of it basic elements implemented as objects, I wouldn't say javascript is inherently an object-oriented language.  You can write straight up scripts that work fine for desired scenarios without any OO practices put into place.

Comment: @Taplar, good to know. Thank you! 
Btw, my question is put on hold because it's very "broad". Should I ask 5 separate questions then?

Comment: Most questions related to Stack Overflow are about resolving issues.  Your question does not seem to be asking about issues that can be solved, but asking for information.  Given that, I'm not sure that Stack Overflow is the best platform for you to ask these questions.  You might ask about this on meta.stackoverflow.com and see what they say.

Comment: @Taplar, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About **NODE.JS :** Node.js is a **JavaScript runtime** not a JS framework. It's built on Chrome's V8 JavaScript engine and enables you to run javascript **outside** the browser.

Comment: Thank you, Hamza!

Answer (score 0):

From [my blog post on this topic](https://organicdonut.com/2013/08/technical-understanding-javascript-node-js-and-their-libraries), which goes into more depth and includes examples:

**JavaScript** is a programming language designed for use in a web browser. (It’s no longer a “scripting” language, nor does it have anything to do with Oracle’s “Java”, so the name is a bit misleading.)

**AJAX** stands for “Asynchronous JavaScript and XML“, and is a way that a webpage can use JavaScript to send and receive data from a server without refreshing a webpage. XML is a kind of markup language – like HTML, which people sometimes use for sending data across the internet. Recently, **JSON** (“JavaScript Object Notation”) is more popular and can be natively read by JavaScript.

**jQuery** is a library built in JavaScript to automate and simplify common tasks. There are many libraries like it, but jQuery really took off because of its power and ability to make things work in older browsers. jQuery is used in the browser, alongside “normal” JavaScript. It is mainly used for animation and AJAX, which are difficult to do with vanilla JavaScript, but are just a few lines in jQuery.

I don't cover **Express.js** in the original post, but you're right. It's a framework for easily writing web servers using node.js.

Comment: Thank you, Erty! Will read the blog post as well! 
Can you share a snippet of code where you can see (almost) all of them working together?

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript

JavaScript is a scripting **language**, originally created by Brendan Eich at Netscape. ECMAScript is a specification trying to standardize Javascript. Back in the day each browser implemented Javascript in their own way, leading to a different and unexpected behavior depending on the clients browser. They still do that now, but the standardization has helped a lot.

It is a multi paradigm language. You can employ both imperative object oriented and functional programming. I actually think that is one of its strengths.

### Node.js

Node.js is **runtime**, i.e. an implementation of the language. It executes Javascript. It is built on top of Chrome's V8 engine. It allows you to run Javascript outside your browser.

### Express.js

Is a web application framework built on Node.js. It allows you to create web applications and APIs using Javascript and running it server-side.

### AJAX

Ajax is a client-side technique (not a library or a framework) where you *asynchronously* and behind the scene send and retrieve data from a server. Instead of standard page refreshes you could instead just update the DOM with the fetched data, or you could upload an image without being redirected.

Its an acronym for *Asynchronous JavaScript And XML*. No one really uses XML anymore though, you'd commonly see JSON instead. Which brings me to:

### JSON

JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is file format that is commonly used for serialization and transmission of data. It is also human readable and it looks A LOT like standard Javascript Objects (hence the name). Example of JSON:

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "age": 28,
  "friends": ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"],
}
```

You'd commonly use this format to send (and retrieve) data between client and server (using Ajax techniques).

It is important to note, that even though it is named after JavaScript, it is very much language agnostic. In fact, JSON is so prevalent that you actually use it a lot more places than just JavaScript.

### jQuery

Is a library for making a lot of the client side scripting easy. It does A LOT of stuff, but for most parts its core feature is DOM manipulation. It also does Ajax and handles events.

Comment: Very clear, Phillip! Thank you! 
Can you give a real, practical example of using them all together?